# In Intellij-IDEA 13, what happened to the tool window buttons that version 12 had?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I installed the community edition of Intellij-IDEA 13 and I lost the tool window buttons on the right, left and bottom.  Here's an image of the buttons on the right in Intellij-IDEA 12:

[image: Intellij-IDEA 12 Tool Window Buttons]

What happened to these?  I can get them to pop up by going to `View -> Tool Windows -> <Pick One>`, but if I close them, I have to go back to the menu to get it to pop up.  This isn't that big of a deal because there are also short cuts attached to *some* of them.  But, I use the "Maven" one frequently, and there's no shortcut attached for that one.

Were these tool window buttons replaced with something better that I haven't discovered yet?  If not, is there a way to get these buttons back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such buttons are invisible by default from left and right side. Click here if you want make them visible: And click again and they will disappear.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was just going to post a screenshot myself.

Comment: Yes, I also find this button a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/intellij-idea-tool-windows.html

There's a button that will bring them right up without resorting to the menu selection.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the tool window buttons are *not* visible, you can double-tab <kbd>alt</kbd> to see them temporarily (the 3 borders containing them pop up), and whilst still holding down alt you can hit the relevant key (e.g. `1` for Project) to choose one.

Similarly, you can use <kbd>ctrl-tab</kbd> and a number to focus a tool window.

I commonly have tool windows visible on my desktop pc and not visible on my laptop (where screen space is limited).

Comment: Is there a way to enable/disable the double-alt functionality?

Comment: Perhaps destroy the alt key with your Atlantean Sword?